# How to change a modem's factory default settings

Tags: firmware, factory-defaults

I have linksys modem (WAG354G) and I will put this modem to far away from home to another house. But I want to use this modem running all the time. In the place where modem will run in, there are lot's of power cut and modem will be back to the factory settings (worse scenario). So, here are options:

1. I want to change factory settings
2. Or if I change firmware and load it for the last I could be achieve my aim

Do you know how to edit firmware?

Comment: I have never heard of a router that looses it's config just because the power is off.

Comment: Of course it doesn't loose its config with only one power cut. But when it happens repeatedly it is returning back to factory default settings. If this happens, I willn't make remote connection because modem wouldn't connect to internet if it returns to factory default.

Comment: I have my computer, printer, router/modem connected to the same powerstrip. I turn that off most evnings and have never had my router loose it's config. If that happened I'd report the router as faulty and get a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me with a router from usrobotics, but for Cisco Linksys I dont think it will happen.Your best bet it to have a backup file of the router configration so you can restore.

Comment: Yes but modem will be another city and I'll be another city ;)

Comment: The only thing I got is throw Dynamic DNS that it is pointing to the router IP address, but it may create a security risk.

Comment: Yes you are right but the most important part is ISP settings. So, it can't connect to internet(ISP). Dynamic DNS is another subject of my purpose.